# How to clear session storage in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, session

I am using $sessionStorage to store the user information after signing in , after all operations while logging out I need to clear session and clear cache.

I am able to set user info in $session but couldn't clear session while logging out. here is my code

```
        if(data!=null && data.accessible == true){

            $sessionStorage.user = JSON.stringify(data); //Storing user info in session          
            $sessionStorage.loggedIn = true;
            $rootScope.loggedIn = true;      
            $rootScope.loggedInuserId = userName;

            $rootScope.menuType=data.defaultMenuType;
            $scope.operational=data.operational;
            $scope.lifeCycle=data.lifeCycle;
            $scope.qbot=data.qbot;
            $scope.admin=data.admin;

            if($scope.admin){
                   $state.go('admin');
                   $scope.menubar = false;
               }
            else if($scope.operational){
               $state.go('dashboard');
               $scope.var1=true;
           }else if ($scope.lifeCycle){
               $state.go('lifecycle');
               $scope.menubar = false;
           }else if ($scope.qbot){
               $scope.menubar = false;
                $state.go('qbot')
           } 

        }else if(data!=null && data.accessible == false){
            $rootScope.registereduser = true;
            $rootScope.loggedIn = false;

        }
```

Now I wanna clear session while logging out. Here is my Code

```
$scope.logout=function(){
    $sessionStorage.clear();
    $rootScope.loggedIn = false;
    $rootScope.registereduser = false;
    $rootScope.registration = false;

}
```

I have used $sessionStorage.clear() , $sessionStorage.remove().. but couldn't . Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Try "delete $sessionStorage"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to clear sessionStorage use `delete $sessionStorage`

Answer (score 2):

You are able to clear all data stored within sessionStorage if required.

In order to clear everything stored by your application within sessionStorage you should use the following:

```
$sessionStorage.empty();
```

See the link http://ghost.scriptwerx.io/angularjs-sessionstorage/

Answer (score 1):

Also try this

```
$sessionStorage.empty();
```